# How to make variables and use arg in spatial.distance.euclidian() by for loop in python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

*First question* is how to make variables by for loop in python3.
I offer example result.

```
box1 = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
box2 = [2.0, 4.0, 6.0]
box3 = [3.0, 6.0, 9.0]
```

Although I tried coding, python3 said `SyntaxError: can't assign to operator`.
My code:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    box + str(i) = [i*i, (i+1)*i, (i+2)*i]
```

*Second question* is how to use arg in spatial.distance.euclidian() by for loop in python3.
spatial.distance.euclidian is scipy method.
tried My code:

```
for i in range(1, 4):    
    print(spatial.distance.euclidian(box1, box + str(i)))
```

Please lend me hands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question: The obvious answer is to use a dictionary for the data. Using a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
box = {i: [i*i, (i+1)*i, (i+2)*i] for i in range(1,4)}
```

If you really want to have variables like box_1, box_2, etc, something like

```
for i in range(1,4):
    exec('box_' + str(i) + ' = [' + str(i*i) + ']')
```

is needed.

Second question:
Using [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) you can create all the pairs from the keys and then calculate the distances of the corresponding lists.

```
from itertools import combinations
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean

for a, b in combinations(box.keys(), 2):
    print(euclidean(box[a], box[b]))
```